# Automating a task

Tags: automation, ui-automation

I'd like to automate a very simple task. 
All I'm doing is exporting projecting files from an application called "solmetric pv analyzer." But I need to do it about 100 times.

Not sure if this information will help, but in order to export the projects, I need to load them into the program and then File->export traces for entire system.

I'd use something like AutoHotKey, but the sizes of the files vary greatly, so the export time does as well and I don't want it to wait such a long time do to each file.

On top of that, I'm stuck on windows XP on a computer with limited processing power.

Windows XP SP2
1 GB RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the flow, if I had to do it - I would use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). It is quite user friendly and

> automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

And does fit well under your hardware requirements

> Windows XP SP2 1 GB RAM

since it only needs [about 200MB memory](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/166082) to start. Once you create your script, I'm sure that the execution will take even less than that.

Aiming at full answer - you can even schedule the execution of the scripts via PowerShell/batch files. Here are the [CLI arguments](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/010-command-line.html) that you can use:

```
usage:
Sikuli-IDE [--args <arguments>] [-h] [-r <sikuli-file>] [-s] [-t <sikuli-file>]
 --args <arguments>             specify the arguments passed to Jython's sys.argv
 -h,--help                      print this help message
 -r,--run <sikuli-file>         run .sikuli or .skl file
 -s,--stderr                    print runtime errors to stderr instead of popping up a message box
 -t,--test <sikuli-file>   run .sikuli as a unit test case with junit's text UI runner
```